# How to initialize a static dictionary property in a Powershell class?

Tags: powershell

Is there any way for a static property in a Powershell class to contain a generic dictionary? Without the initialisation syntax that exists in C#, I haven't found a way to do it.

```
enum Environment
{
    Production
    QA
    Dev
}

class Config
{
    # How to get this populated?
    static [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[Environment, hashtable]] $EnvData
}
```

Potential workarounds:

1. Add-Type and a C# class
2. A GetEnvData() method

Is there a better way I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in C#, you can use the static constructor (which is what initializers are syntactic sugar for, anyway):

```
class Config
{
    static [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[Environment, hashtable]] $EnvData

    static Config() {
        $d = New-Object ([System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[Environment, hashtable]])
        $d["Production"] = @{Setting="Foo"}

        [Config]::EnvData = $d
    }
}
```

The use of a local is not strictly required, but I sleep better knowing the initialization is atomic.

You can *also* use an initializer (`$EnvData = ...`) but that's a little tricky in this case, since creating a generic `Dictionary` in one statement is, well, awkward, and the class syntax doesn't like it if you get complicated (pipes, nested function calls). You could still, if you so wanted, split off initialization into a separate hidden static function and call that for initialization (`... $EnvData = [Config]::initialEnvData()`), which may be more readable than one big constructor if you've got many conceptually independent properties.

Comment: That's marvellous, thank you! I hadn't come across the static constructor before.